# Microsoft Flow for datetime between 2 times

Tags: power-automate

I am looking to create a microsoft flow to check if an email was received between 18:00 and 18:15 Pacific Time. Ideally this would be a single formula instead of comparing `time >= 18:00` and `time <= 18:15`

Currently I have:

```
convertTimeZone(triggerOutputs()?['body/receivedDateTime'], 'UTC', 'Pacific Standard Time', 'HH:mm')
```

to convert the datetime from UTC to PST in `HH:mm` format. My next thought was to subtract a time (`18:00`) from this and get the difference in minutes, then checking that this value is between 0 and 15

Answer (score 0):

I've broken out my answer but you can do what you need with it.  Personally, I think this is the most transparent and easiest approach but it's up to you.

**Flow**

[image: Flow]

To break it down ...

**Firstly**, the first step is me merely initialising a string that can be used to get the time from.

**Next**, I transform the minutes into an integer using the following expression (change out the locale as needed) ...

```
int(formatDateTime(parseDateTime(variables('Received DateTime'), 'en-AU', 'yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm'), 'HHmm'))
```

**Finally**, I do the comparison using this expression ...

```
and(greaterOrEquals(variables('Time Integer'), 1800), lessOrEquals(variables('Time Integer'), 1815))
```

#### Invalid

[image: Invalid]

#### Valid

[image: Valud]